# Organizing functionally identical assertions by test cases from tests-are-docs point of view

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions, bdd, methodology

I'm trying to polish my BDD practices, and I've came over this problem. Here is simple data structure class (trimmed down for brevity):

```
class Geometry(object):
    def __init__(self, *, bytes_per_sector, sectors_count):
        self.bytes_per_sector = bytes_per_sector
        self.sectors_count = sectors_count

        ...
```

And I have following tests for it in some pseudo-language:

```
# "describe" are test suites
# "it" are test cases
# "when" are subtests

describe geometry:
    describe constructor:
        it creates geometry object:
            expect `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 512)` to be instance of
                                                            Geometry class

        describe bytes per sector argument: 
            it is required:
                when given:
                    expect `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 512)` not to raise

                when missing:
                    expect `Geometry(cnt = 390487680)` to raise TypeError

            it is okay (???):
                expect each of these not to raise:
                    # lower bound
                    `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 1)`

                    # higher bound
                    `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 65535)`

                    # non-power of 2
                    `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 42)`

                    # odd
                    `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 123)`

                    # typical
                    `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 512)`

                    # advanced format
                    `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 4096)`

            it cannot be zero:
                expect `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 0)` to raise ValueError

            it cannot be negative:
                expect each of these to raise ValueError:
                    `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = -1)`
                    `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = -512)`
                    `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = -4096)`

            it cannot be larger than 16 bits:
                expect `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 65535)` not to raise

                expect each of these to raise ValueError:
                    `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 65536)`
                    `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 65537)`
                    `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 100000)`

            it cannot be of wrong type:
                expect each of these to raise TypeError:
                    when float:
                        `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 3.14)`
                        `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = -3.14)`

                    when string:
                        `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = '512')`
                        `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = '')`

                    when none:
                        `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = None)`

                    when list:
                        `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = [])`
                        `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = [512])`

                    when tuple:
                        `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = ())`
                        `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = (512, ))`

                    when dict:
                        `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = {})`
                        `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = {512: 1024})`
```

I don't know what to do with `it is okay` test. Actual implementation does not really distinguish between non-power of two, odd and other kinds of numbers, so I might as well add something like "prime numbers are good too" check.

However, despite being nearly useless from code point of view, I try to design test cases that way so they can also serve as additional examples for the reader. That way, I suppose, reader can learn that my code is tolerant to strange sector sizes, so those assertions might not be that useless after all.

So, given this background, the thing I wonder about is:

> When designing positive branch test cases in BDD, should one group all functionally identical assertions under single test case:
>
> ```
> it should be okay:
>     # lower bound
>     `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 1)`
>
>     # higher bound
>     `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 65535)`
>
>     # odd
>     `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 123)`
>
>     ...
> ```
>
> or should one separate each functionally identical expectation in its own test case?
>
> ```
> it should not fail given lower bound:
>     `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 1)`
>
> it should not fail given upper bound:
>     `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 65535)`
>
> it should not fail given odd value:
>     `Geometry(cnt = 390487680, bps = 123)`
> ```

And while I am on it — what is correct, commonly understood wording for combined positive branch test cases? I assume it's not "it should be okay", right?